# How to tell pandas to read columns from the left?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a csv in which one header column is missing. Eg, I have n data columns, but n-1 header names. When this happens, it seems like pandas shifts my first column to be an index, as shown in the image. So what happens is the column to the right of date_time in the csv, is under the date_time column in the pandas data frame.

My question is: how can I force pandas to read from the left so that the date_time data remains under the date_time column instead of becoming the index? I'm thinking if pandas can simply read from left to right and add dummy column names at the end of the file, that would be great.

Side note: I concede that my input csv should be "clean", however, I think that pandas/frameworks in general should be able to handle the case in which some data might be unclean, but the user wants to proceed with the analysis instead of spending 30 minutes writing a side function/script to fix these minor issues. In my case, the data I care about is *usually* in the first 15 columns and I don't really care if the columns after that are misaligned. However, when I read the dataframe into pandas, I'm forced to care and waste time fixing these issues even though I don't care about the remaining columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't care about the last column, just set `index_col=False`

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False)
```

That way, it will sequentially match the columns with data for the first `n-1` columns. Data after that will not be in the data frame

---

You may also skip the first row to have all your data in the data frame first

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1)
```

and then just set the column name after

```
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', ....] + ['dummy_col1', 'dummy_col2'...]
```

where the first list comes from the `row=0` of your csv, and the second list you just fill dinamically with a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Looks like exactly what I need